# Error retrieving Entry with AreaName in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to perform a get with multiple parameters in node.js . I have the following files

**entry.routes.js**

```
module.exports = app => {
  const entry = require("../controlers/entry.controller.js");

  // Retrieve a single Entry with Id
  app.get("/entry/:Id", entry.findOne);


  app.get("/energy/api/ActualTotalLoad/:AreaName/:Resolution/:Year/:Month/:Day", entry.find1a);

};
```

**ActualTotalLoad.model.js**

```
const sql = require("./db.js");

// constructor
const Entry = function(entry) {
  this.Id=entry.Id
};

Entry.findByPk = (Id, result) => {
  sql.query(`SELECT * FROM ActualTotalLoad WHERE Id = ${Id}`, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(err, null);
      return;
    }

    if (res.length) {
      console.log("found entry: ", res[0]);
      result(null, res[0]);
      return;
    }

    // not found Customer with the id
    result({ kind: "not_found" }, null);
  });
};

Entry.findBy1a = (AreaName,Resolution,Year,Month,Day,result) => {
  sql.query(`SELECT AreaName,AreaTypeCodeId,MapCodeId,ResolutionCodeId,Year,Month,Day FROM ActualTotalLoad WHERE AreaName = ${AreaName} AND ResolutionCodeId = ${Resolution} AND Year = ${Year} AND Month = ${Month} AND Day = ${Day}` , (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(err, null);
      return;
    }

    if (res.length) {
      console.log("found entry: ", res[0]);
      result(null, res[0]);
      return;
    }

    // not found Customer with the id
    result({ kind: "not_found" }, null);
  });
};

module.exports=Entry;
```

and the file: **entry.controller.js**

```
const Entry = require("../models/ActualTotalLoad.model.js");

// Find a single Customer with a customerId
exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
   Entry.findByPk(req.params.Id, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      if (err.kind === "not_found") {
        res.status(404).send({
          message: `Not found Entry with id ${req.params.Id}.`
        });
      } else {
        res.status(500).send({
          message: "Error retrieving Entry with id " + req.params.Id
        });
      }
    } else res.send(data);
  });
};


exports.find1a = (req, res) => {
   Entry.findBy1a(req.params.AreaName,req.params.Resolution,req.params.Year,req.params.Month,req.params.Day, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      if (err.kind === "not_found") {
        res.status(404).send({
          message: `Not found Entry with AreaName ${req.params.AreaName}.`
        });
      } else {
        res.status(500).send({
          message: "Error retrieving Entry with AreaName " + req.params.AreaName
        });
      }
    } else res.send(data);
  });
};
```

I am trying to perform this get http://localhost:8765/energy/api/ActualTotalLoad/DE-AT-LU/7/2018/1/4

But I get the error   "message": "Error retrieving Entry with AreaName DE-AT-LU"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your WHERE statement like this

```sql
   SELECT ... WHERE AreaName = "${AreaName}" AND ResolutionCodeId = ${Resolution} AND Year = ${Year} AND Month = ${Month} AND Day = ${Day}
```

Note: notice the quotes ( *"${AreaName}"* )

AreaName in your DB schema is problably typed as string (or text), so you need to quote you search criteria as string (surrounding it by `"` or `'`)

I assume that `ResolutionCodeId`, `Year` `Month`, and `Day` are number types, so it's ok to not quote them.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. I tried your code but still get the error. Then I removed the AreaName from the where statement and still got the error.

Comment: can you console.log the full error?

`else { console.log(err)
        res.status(500).send({
          message: "Error retrieving Entry with AreaName " + req.params.AreaName
        });
      }`